# Javascript - traversing through object and updating property

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration, tree-traversal

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a JavaScript object like the following ...

```
var category = [{
    isExpanded: false,
    name: "Electricals",
    subcategories: [{
        isExpanded: false,
        name: "Audio",
        subcategories: null
    }, {
        isExpanded: false,
        name: "Photography",
        subcategories: null
    }]
}, {
    isExpanded: false,
    name: "Telecoms",
    subcategories: [{
        isExpanded: false,
        name: "Mobile",
        subcategories: null
    }, {
        isExpanded: false,
        name: "Sim-cards",
        subcategories: null
    }]
}, {
    isExpanded: false,
    name: "Entertainment",
    subcategories: [{
        isExpanded: false,
        name: "Gaming",
        subcategories: [{
            isExpanded: false,
            name: "Games",
            subcategories: null
        }]
    }, {
        isExpanded: false,
        name: "Sports",
        subcategories: null
    }]
}];
```

My goal is to iterate through each category/subcategory and set the value of 'isExpandable' depending on my logic. Can some advise how I can iterate through through each subcategory of the object, baring in mind that a subcategory and also have a subcategory and so on?

Here is my current attempt ...

```
function blah() {
  for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
    if (category[i].subcategories) {
      console.log(category[i]);
      traverseCategoryTree(category[i]);
    }
  }
}

function traverseCategoryTree(category) {
  //iterate each subcategory and update is Expanded. 
}

blah();
```

Comment: use a recursive function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function traverseCategoryTree(categories) {
  for (var i = 0, len = categories.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(categories[i]);
    if (categories[i].subcategories) {
      traverseCategoryTree(categories[i].subcategories);
    }
  }
}    

traverseCategoryTree(category);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. We are using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme) for most of our data processing now. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how it would work for your example:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const modify = (data) => objectScan(['**[*]'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => {
    value.isExpandable = (
      Array.isArray(value.subcategories)
      && value.subcategories.length !== 0
    );
  }
})(data);

const category = [{ isExpanded: false, name: 'Electricals', subcategories: [{ isExpanded: false, name: 'Audio', subcategories: null }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Photography', subcategories: null }] }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Telecoms', subcategories: [{ isExpanded: false, name: 'Mobile', subcategories: null }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Sim-cards', subcategories: null }] }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Entertainment', subcategories: [{ isExpanded: false, name: 'Gaming', subcategories: [{ isExpanded: false, name: 'Games', subcategories: null }] }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Sports', subcategories: null }] }];

console.log(modify(category)); // how many matched found
// => 10

console.log(category);
// => [ { isExpanded: false, name: 'Electricals', subcategories: [ { isExpanded: false, name: 'Audio', subcategories: null, isExpandable: false }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Photography', subcategories: null, isExpandable: false } ], isExpandable: true }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Telecoms', subcategories: [ { isExpanded: false, name: 'Mobile', subcategories: null, isExpandable: false }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Sim-cards', subcategories: null, isExpandable: false } ], isExpandable: true }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Entertainment', subcategories: [ { isExpanded: false, name: 'Gaming', subcategories: [ { isExpanded: false, name: 'Games', subcategories: null, isExpandable: false } ], isExpandable: true }, { isExpanded: false, name: 'Sports', subcategories: null, isExpandable: false } ], isExpandable: true } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)